# Sorting DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am trying to sort my bootstrap-datatable using the HTML5 attribut data-order but it does not seem to be working.. I want the biggest Work Order Number to show 1st

Can anyone help me out and let me know what I am doing wrong?

This is what my code looks like

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable responsive" data-order="WO">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>WO</th>
        <th>Client Name</th>                
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>ABC</td> 
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>DEF</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>GHI</td> 
    </tr>  
</tbody>
```

This is what I have in my JavaScript

```
$('.datatable').dataTable({
    "order": [0, "desc"],       
    "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span12'i><'span12 center'p>>",
    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
    "oLanguage": {
        "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the 1.10 API method with an older version it appears.  [Here's a conversion document](http://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert) to show you the old vs. new terminology.  You mention HTML5 sort method, but I don't think you're trying that at all....this is a simple column sorting example.

For what you're doing, it appears you want `aaSorting`

Here is the [old API reference](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref) to give you an example.

Comment: Thank you for the link I did not realize I was looking at the documentation from the wrong version

Answer (score 0):

Change `"order": [0, "desc"]` to `"order": [[0, "desc"]]`

Comment: I tested that but it still did not work, I had to changed order to aaSorting.. Can you explain why I need to have double brackets []..

Comment: Using this parameter you can define which column(s) the order is performed upon, and the ordering direction. The orderDT must be an array of arrays, please refer to http://datatables.net/reference/option/order